# what is the change that happens on LMS when cmi.exit is changed from suspend to logout?

Tags: scorm

What are the data that is cleared when the cmi.exit is changed from suspend to logout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SCORM 2004, if the value of cmi.exit is not set to suspend, the entire CMI data model is reset. In SCORM 1.2, it is a little ambiguous what is supposed to happen if cmi.exit is not set to suspend, some LMS's reset the data while others preserve it. In general, preserving it is the recommended behavior.

Comment: when you say the entier CMI data model you mean including the cmi.completion_status cmi.success_status everything or is it just cmi.location and cmi.suspend_data

Comment: All of it, including completion and success status.